# Where does Arzela-Ascoli thm fail in this case?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n=1/n$. Then {$f_n$} is uniformly bounded by 1 and equicontinuous. 
However, {$f_n$} does not have a convergent subsequence. Why does Ascoli fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arzela-Ascoli can be stated in a few different ways. One is "a uniformly bounded, uniformly equicontinuous sequence of real-valued functions on a compact metric space has a subsequence which converges uniformly to some continuous function". Note that this limit need not be a member of the sequence. When restated in terms of point-set topology, Arzela-Ascoli says "a uniformly bounded, uniformly equicontinuous set of functions is precompact". It does not say that such a set is actually compact.

A similar situation in the real numbers is "any sequence in a bounded set of real numbers has a subsequence which converges to some real number"--but not all bounded sets of real numbers are closed.

Comment: would fn=n count as a uniformly convergent sequence then?

Comment: $f_n(x)=n$ is not a uniformly bounded sequence.

Comment: yes, you are right, but would it be considered a uniformly convergent sequence?

Comment: No. Why would it be?

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean "$\{f_n\}$ does not have a convergent subsequence"?

The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero.

Comment: 0 is not in {f_n} though

Comment: So? $\ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: {f_n} is not compact, which is what ascoli claims.

Comment: It is very rare for a sequence to be compact. I still fail to see where you are going with this. Arzela-Ascoli says that a bounded equicontinuous sequence (acting on an interval) has a uniformly convergent subsequence, which is exactly what happens above.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong i thought this sequence does not have a uniformly convergent subsequence since the limit is not in the set {f_n}.

Comment: "Wrong" might not be the right word, because we are talking language here. The concept of sequences and subsequence has nothing to do with limits. The **sequence** $\{1/n\}$ is a convergent sequence; its limit (zero) is not a number in the sequence. Like I said above, it is kind of unusual for the limit of a sequence to appear as an entry in the sequence.

Comment: seems like instead of calling it unformly convergent, seems like unformly cauchy is a better name?

Comment: @user1559897 No, it is not. We say that the sequence of reals $1\over n $ converges, after all. Convergence does not mean that the sequence contains its limit, merely that *the space the sequence lives in* contains its limit. Now, saying that a a sequence converges requires us to fix a space for that sequence to live in, but this is indeed done in A-A.

Comment: @user1559897 The sequence is compact, RELATIVE to the space it's in, which is the space of continuous functions. Your sequences converges uniformly to 0, which is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing compactness with sequential compactness. Sequential compactness means that bounded sequences have convergent subsequences.

Moreover, Arzela-Ascoli does not state that the space is sequentially compact anyway. It merely gives a characterization of when convergent subsequences can be extracted.

In this case, your sequence is convergent. So every subsequence converges, and Arzela-Ascoli is mosquito-nuking, as there is no need to use such a tool to extract anything at all.

Comment: the book i am reading is talking everything in terms of a metric space.